# NAS/ mini server for first own home

Tags: server, nas

At the end of this year I will no longer be able to use the off the shelf QNAP TS-251+ NAS my parents bought a while ago as I am moving, thus I want to build my first own setup.
At the moment I am the only one using it for more than just a SMB file server, but I cannot take it with me.
Here are some of the specs of said system:

- **CPU:** Intel® Celeron® J1900 4-core/4-thread processor, burst up to 2.42 GHz, 64-bit x86
- **GPU:** Intel® HD Graphics
- **RAM:** 8GB DDR3
- **Storage:** 2 times 3TB WD RED NAS drives in RAID 1

(Full specs [here](https://www.qnap.com/en/product/ts-251+/specs/hardware))

I use at nominal usage about 2/3 of the RAM and 10% of the processing power, but I have a few Docker containers running 24/7 which need the reserves, namely a Jellyfin server that does some transcoding from time to time. At the moment I am running

- SMB file server for my Windows Laptop (QNAP software)
- Photo management system with facial recognition and stuff (QNAP software, no replacement found yet)
- Web Access to files via browser (QNAP software, probably to be replaced with NextCloud or similar)
- OpenVPN server (QNAP integrated software)
- Calibre Server for my ebooks (Docker)
- Speedtest Tracker (Docker)
- Jellyfin Server (Docker)

But I have plans for

- Bitwarden/Vaultwarden
- PI-Hole
- simple Website (like digital business card)

For my own setup I would like to start with something that is not prebuilt because I had some problems with the QNAP software in the recent years.
(I think) I need at least the following, but correct me if you think I am wrong:

- 8GM RAM
- 2 Connectors for HDD drives, better 4
- 1 GBit Ethernet

I have had a look into starting from a RasPI 4 8GB, but they are so expensive at the moment, and I can't see any project where I would need the primary feature of a PI (namely the GPIO pins) so I thought maybe there is some similarly energy efficient other board to start with. Can anyone recommend something? If possible I'd like to stay under 300€ for the build (without the drives, I know that they are going to be the biggest investment), but if I can't I will see.